# Q: JasperReport (Jaspersoft Studio 6.17.0) repeats character in text field

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a pretty weird issue regarding JasperReports.
I made a test PDF file, since we have to swap our reporting tools to JasperReports, and I tried to just play around with a static text and another dynamic text field, which contains one single java.Math.BigDecimal (tried it with another Integer variable, though).

**Here's the issue:**

Both the static text field (which should contain "troll", yeah...creative) and the dynamic text field are printed in the final exported PDF....although, both the first character of this text field and the length are quite fine, but everything after the first character is just filled up with the same character...means: instead of "troll" it will print "ttttt" and instead of any number (even decimals) between 30000.00-39999.99 will be printed as "33333333" (yep, even the dot will be subbed with a "3").

Here's the source code of the **test-PDF-jrxml**:

```
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="7d73e29c-3d01-4b41-9f1e-a969f0f9e3fc">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="cases" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="sum" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="66">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="206" y="36" width="100" height="30" uuid="0855f093-7bf7-44d3-986b-2cffbca10f96"/>
                <text><![CDATA[troll]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="139" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="100" y="1" width="271" height="30" uuid="778cb21b-f90f-486d-82cc-91fce9edfc3c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sum}.floatValue();   $F{cases}.intValue();]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And the **method of our Java-Code** which should handle creating the PDF-file.

```
    private void jasperWriteList(final Document pDoc) {
        PaymentClass payment= pDoc.getGrpHdr().getPayment();
        String path = randomPathDummyHere;
        
        BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        int cases= 0;
        
        try {
            //Compiles jrxml-draft for sum list
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("Blank_A4.jrxml");
            
            //Parsing from original
            for (PaymentCase pCase : pDoc.getCases().getCase()){
                cases++;
                sum = sum.add(pCase.getSum());
            }
            
            //DataSource and stuff      
            SumListJRData slData = new SumListJRData(sum, cases);
            JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Collections.singletonList(slData));
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, (JRDataSource)dataSource);
//WE SUSPECT THE ERROR IN THIS VERY STEP, SINCE DEBUG HAS SHOWN PERFECTLY FINE VARIABLES TILL HERE
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, path);           
        } catch (JRException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

We tried to debug this one, and you can see in the comment of the code, where we suspect the error to be. But we had to dig deeper into the source code than in Minecrafts Nether and still weren't able to find the error. Maybe it's a bug inside of the Jasper package itself? Or did we do something wrong somewhere?

**Our tech stack is:**

Jaspersoft Studio 6.17.0

Java JDK 1.8.0_292

Eclipse Spring Tool Suite 4 (4.5.0.RELEASE)

*Thanks in advance :)*

Comment: `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sum}.floatValue();   $F{cases}.intValue();]]></textFieldExpression>` - it is not working like this

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem though, since we already tried stuff like formatting like a String or create this text line entirely with the Jaspersoft design GUI.
Furthermore, at least the static text field should work normal...
Both text fields work normal in the preview, but as soon as this will be written as a file, the issue occurs.

Comment: It is a quite old question, but how did you solved it?